# Automatic compilation of parent templates

Tags: python, templates, cheetah

I am trying to setup dynamic compilation of Cheetah templates, useful for development (so I don't have to recompile them with `cheetah compile` after each change).  Seems like `Cheetah.Template.Template` is right API for that, but it simply doesn't handle parent templates.

So if I have:

```
 -- __init__.py
 -- index.tmpl:
    #extends layout.A
 -- layout/
          -- __init__.py
          -- A.tmpl:
          #echo 'Hello!'
```

If I run Python in root directory, I'd get the next:

```
>>> from Cheetah.Template import Template; t = Template(file='index.tmpl')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Cheetah-2.4.3-py2.6-freebsd-7-amd64.egg/Cheetah/Template.py", line 1259, in __init__
    self._compile(source, file, compilerSettings=compilerSettings)
  ...
  ImportError: No module named A
```

If I compile `A.tmpl` with `cheetah compile`, error disappears, but changes in template doesn't affect result of `index.tmpl` compilation:

```
$ cat layout/A.tmpl
#echo 'Hello, world!'

$ python
>>> from Cheetah.Template import Template; t = Template(file='index.tmpl')
>>> str(t)
'Hello!'
```

Should I recompile all parent templates by myself (e.g. like `Aquarium` framework does)?

*Cheetah version 2.4.*

Any tips about Django1.3\Cheetah integration are also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some where early in your process startup, include the following two lines:

```
import Cheetah.ImportHooks 
Cheetah.ImportHooks.install()
```

I believe this will give you the behavior you are looking for.

This is not documented in the main docs, but Tavis Rudd suggested this in response to a  similar question on the [Cheetah mailing list](http://old.nabble.com/Cheetah%27s--include-base-directory-td26952548.html).